# How include file depending on pagename

Tags: php, html

I have a quite simple site built with html. All pages are built with header page and footer. The header contains logo and menu.

On one page I want to show the content in a database and I have the php collecting the data on top of the page.

Now I want to use the same system with header and footer for that page so I want to include the php in the header only if the pagename is the one where the data should be presented. Is this possible? Something like If pagename is then

Regards

Anders

Comment: Use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and put the urls in if conditions

Comment: Hi
Can you perhaps be a little more specific how it should look?

TIA
Anders

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of how you can implement it in header, there can be better ideas but you can give it a try

```
$my_current_page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($my_current_page_url == "http://www.mywebsite.com/abc"){
   include("content_for_abc.php");
} else if($my_current_page_url == "http://www.mywebsite.com/abc1"){
   include("content_for_abc1.php");
} else ..
   //so on
```

Where `http://www.mywebsite.com/abc1` is the url of your page you want to include the code for

There are other ways around too , but you can give it a try.

**Logic** : The logic is fetch the current url using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then match it with static urls for the pages you have created and then include the code in the if conditions.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing. If the url is not the page where I want to include the script then I jst want it to load normal. Meaning the rest comes after the else.?

Comment: Yes to the question . For additional info If there is content you want to load on all pages then put it outside the if else structure !